# The proper way of getting the value of a TimeField in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, jinja2, timefield

Imagine that in a Educational Management System I have created a form for entering the details for a ,let say, course. After I save it to the database(in my case postgres) I want to provide the user with the opportunity to edit the previously saved form. So I have to initialise a form with the initial values that user has previously entered. Everything is Alright but the problem is that I cannot format the the TIME input (let say the time that course starts) received from the database into a proper shape to be suitable for  in my html. So the initial value is not shown in the time input.How can I solve this problem?

initial form:

```
<form  action="/courses/new_course/" method="POST">
     <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3   p-2">
            <label for="due_exam_time">Due Exam Time:</label>
            <input type="time" name="due_exam_time" >
      </div>
</form>
```

The same form with the previously-user-entered value for updating the value of the time input

```
<form  action="/courses/update_course/{{ course.id }}" method="POST">
         <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3   p-2">
                <label for="due_exam_time">Due Exam Time:</label>
                <input type="time" name="due_exam_time" value={{course.start_time}} >
          </div>
    </form>
```

The format of the **course.start_time** is not suitable for time input of html so it remain empty like --:--

Comment: Please post the code you have written.

Comment: you can use template built in tags to format time, date and datetime https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date